Why am I getting error while nunning npm run dev?
The following error is showing:
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall open
npm error path C:\Users\Acer\package.json
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Acer\package.json'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-03T08_52_08_249Z-debug-0.log

I want to run npm run dev. Node.js is installed in C:/Program Files and cmd directory is C:/User/Acer

Hard to expand on what the error tells you: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Acer\package.json'.

Apparently, you're not running it inside a Node project directory, no package.json found.

This error means that package.json file doesn't exist in your main directory.
To create this file ,run this command inside your project from cmd or from code editor terminal.

npm init

